# Console Output in Windows Service in VS.Net 2008

Tags: c#, windows-services, console

I am using Windows Service using C#.I want an output in Console say Console.WriteLine("Hello").I am not able to get that whereas I am able to successfully write it make an eventLog Entry.

```
  eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");         
            DBSyncHandler sync = new DBSyncHandler();
            sync.startSync();

        }
```

Say therefore I am not able to check whether it is writing to Console and executing below mentioned code.

Comment: If you're writing a service you don't have a console, use the event log instead.

Comment: Hi Jon .Thanks.But how will I come to know whether the Code has been executed...Do you mena I need to write it to EventLog at each step where earlier Console was.Say In DbSyncHandler Class when creating an instance ,there are stages where console display is used.Do you mean I need to use EventLog there to check how much code is been executed in DBSyncHandler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean `Debug.WriteLine` don't you ?  If so, use the sysinternals [debug viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to watch every debug message send by any application (including services)

**edit :** Step by step

1. Replace the `Console.WriteLine` by `Debug.WriteLine`
2. Download [debug viewer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647)
3. Run debug viewer and start your service
4. Debug Viewer will show you every message send to Debug. (you can filter to only see what's interresting for you)
5. Voila !

Comment: Can you elaborate little more. I need to know how 

` DBSyncHandler sync = new DBSyncHandler(); sync.startSync(); 
is getting executed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have no Console window available within a windows service; the option I would use would be to use a logging framework (such as log4net) to output the statements to a log file

Answer (score 0):

In order to see Console output in a Windows Service, you need to set up your service with "Allow the service to interact with Desktop"

```
Control Panel --> Admin Tools --> Services --> select yours --> (right-click) Properties --> Logon Tab --> Tick "Allow service to interact with Desktop"
```

Comment: @developer82 and then any `Console.WriteLine ` statements that you have on your service will be displayed on the typical DOS prompt.

Comment: How do I attach the DOS prompt to the service? Thanks

Comment: I too need an answer to this?